# How to create an Android Food label QR code

Tags: java, android

Hi All I am trying to develop a feature of my app, where I create a food label qr scanner. I want to be able to scan something with my phones camera and I will be returned a list view of all the nutritional information. I have not been able to find anything online in terms of any tutorials. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Let's try https://github.com/search?q=android+qr Most QR libs come with an example application which you can download / fork, eg https://github.com/blikoon/QRCodeScanner

Comment: They all seem to be just regular QR scanners, I need something that will show me the nutritional information. Is there any tutorials online as I cannot seem to find them. It would be more beneficial for my learning to follow a tutorial instead of copying code

Answer (score 0):

To full fill your requirement, App/module which created the QR code initially should have included all the nutritional values.
So your app can read that string and show. So chase down the source app and include the data there and your app can process and display.